# Calculating Unique Addresses In Word Addressable Memory

Tags: memory-hardware, memory-access

According to a textbook assigned for my class, if I have memory that is 
4M X 16, to address this memory (assuming word addressing), we need to be able to uniquely identify $2^{12}$ different items, which means we need $2^{12}$ different addresses. I've been racking my brain, and I can't seem to figure out **how** they're coming up with the value of $2^{12}$ unique addresses.. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What does "4M X 16" mean? In any case, this seems to be a typo. $2^{12}=4096$, whereas $2^{22}$ is about four million.

Comment: According to the book: Memory is often referred to using the notation L  X W (length   width). For example, 4M X 16 means the memory is 4M long (it has 4M = $2^2$   $2^{20}$ = $2^22$ words) and it is 16 bits wide (each word is 16 bits).

Comment: So i'm given to understand that 4M is actually 4MB (megabits)